# Trying to implement a overlay for a gallery-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm an absolute beginner, so sorry for asking stupid questions.

To train I am trying to implement a "lightbox-gallery" to my gallery.

Right now I'm working on the overlay. This code is to blend the overlay in (it's working):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').click(function() {
        $('#overlay').addClass("overlay").fadeIn("slow");

    })
});
```

This code is to get rid of the overlay:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#overlay').live('click', function() {
        $('#overlay').removeClass('overlay');
    });
});
```

However, it's not working. Can anybody give me a hint?

edit: the css:

```
.overlay {
background: black;
z-index: 10;    
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 0.7;

}
```

Comment: Define "not working"? Does your overlay appear but not disappear? If such is the case, check if your problem is fixed when you used `fadeOut()` with:
`$('#overlay').removeClass('overlay').fadeOut()`.

Comment: You'll need to include the CSS for the `overlay` class.

Comment: not working = appears but does not disappear.

Comment: jquery 2.1.3. is the version i am using.

Answer (score 0):

I like this one because it's so little code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#testButton").click(function() {$('#overlayContainer').show();});
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/schaudhary/RNe4T/light/)**

Techniques like this is great because it's pure CSS3!

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#overlay{ /* we set all of the properties for are overlay */
    height:80%;
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:white;
    color:black;
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:5%;
    left:10%;
    z-index:1000;
    display:none;
    /* CSS 3 */
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

#mask{ /* create are mask */
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index:500;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
}
/* use :target to look for a link to the overlay then we find are mask */
#overlay:target, #overlay:target + #mask{
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
}
.close{ /* to make a nice looking pure CSS3 close button */
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    right:-20px;
    background:red;
    color:white;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:35px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    -webkit-border-radius:40px;
    -moz-border-radius:40px;
    -o-border-radius:40px;
    border-radius:40px;
}
#open-overlay{ /* open the overlay */
    padding:10px 5px;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshMesser/vbMw3/)

But if you have a semi-large website. I still recommend the only [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) for expecting multiple instances. Plus there is simple configurations for iFrame and alot of other options.

```
$("#TheFancybox").html("<p>Just adding a paragraph to demonstrate that you can dynamically create HTML content within a DIV using .html()</p>");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/webdevem/5EV8r/)

Comment: thank you very much! In the end i used fancybox. I guess i need a little more experience to do something like this on my own.

Comment: Gladed it helped you! @Dyon Fancybox is legit - also a good one I forgot; Twitter Bootstrap Modal. http://jsfiddle.net/jschr/3kgbG/